# How to properly make a UIView work in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, interface-builder

I have a custom view that I would like to use in Interface Builder. It's setup like the following:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initialize {
....
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    ...frame stuff
}
```

but when I use the class in interface builder it is not receiving the frame, just it's bounds. Meaning the origin stays at 0,0 but the width/height do get set correctly. If anyone can point out whats wrong I would be very greatful.

**UPDATE:**

Just spotted this in IB:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `- (void)awakeFromNib;` for your custom view. At that point, your frame should be setup.

Comment: The IB alert is informing you that your view probably has constraints that will result in it not showing as you are seeing it in IB. You can either update the constraints to match the current IB setup or update the frames to match the constraints. Look for the related menu entries in IB that deal with auto layout issues or use the buttons on the lower right of the IB workspace.